# LXC With rootfs as ContainerName.img

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, mount

So, I am messing around with LXC on my Ubuntu 16.04 box.

I want/need to setup my containers `rootfs` as a specifically sized image.  (No, zfs will not work in my case)

So, I have everything setup and working perfectly via creation of the container(s) through a bash script, and now I am needing to add the mount to my host machines `fstab` to persist the mount on host machine reboots

All this works fine, the container/.img/mounts all create and work wondefully, persisting through reboots.

Now, on container destruction, I need to remove that line from `fstab` as I will not need it to be mounted once the container is destroyed... I know I could probably just leave it without harm, but for sakes of keeping my `fstab` clean, let's say I **need** to do it.   trick is, I would like to be able to do this via shell script, so I do not have to manually edit my `fstab` file everytime I deem it necessary to destroy a container.

I am adding the line with the following

```
    T=$(grep -ir "/home/containers/$UsersName/rootfs" /etc/fstab);
    if [ ! -n $T ]; then
        echo "/home/$UsersName.img   /home/containers/$UsersName/rootfs    xfs   noatime    0       0" >> /etc/fstab;
        mount -a;
    fi;
```

Where `$UserName` = a pre-specified string.

How can I remove that line through my bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this answer on how to delete a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-lines-in-a-text-file-that-containing-a-specific-string). There are several ways to accomplish it but there are several caveats like escaping strings and matching patterns. This makes it hard to give a catch all answer.

`sed` is fast an easy but requires a escaping of slashes in your case. 
A reverse grep (`grep -v`) would probably work well for you. Just make sure nothing unwanted is matched.

In your example: `grep -v "$UsersName.img" /etc/fstab > /etc/fstab.bak; mv /etc/fstab.bak /etc/fstab`

Every line except those containing gets matched and redirected to fstab.bak and finally renamed to fstab.

Comment: Bingo mate.   Aye, `sed` is fast, but this definately does the trick.  For my EC2 servers, I don't expect anymore than a few containers on each, so this will be perfect.    Thanks a bunch!